# Form to assign a parent's child_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this solution is fairly attainable...I just haven't been able to attain it yet -

I have an app that has multiple districts. I also have a model called Person. A person can either be a candidate -- in which case they belong to the district, or they are an incumbent, in which case the district belongs to them.

Here is my existing association:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :district, inverse_of: :candidates, class_name: 'District', optional: true, 
has_one :incumbent_district, inverse_of: :incumbent, class_name: 'District', optional: true

class District < ApplicationRecord
has_many :candidates, inverse_of: :district, class_name: 'Person'
belongs_to :incumbent, inverse_of: :incumbent_district, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'incumbent_id', optional: true
```

On the form where I create a Person, if they are an incumbent, I'd like a drop-down menu to select which District is their's -- ultimately editing the table of Districts to modify the "incumbent_id" field to set it as the Person I am currently creating. I know how to do this for setting the parent on a form, but am stuck figuring out the child part.

Any guidance would be appreciated!